# Getting Follower and FollwedBy Users from Table in one list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table that tracks followers

```
FollowerUserId, FollowingUserId
1                   2
2                   1
3                   1
4                   1
1                   5
```

I want to get all user that given Id follows and is followed by  or Both.
for example for UserId 1,**I want result to be:** (FG: Following, FD: Followed, B: Both ways)

```
2,B
5,FG
3,FD
4,FD
```

i can easily get FG and FD by doing union

```
Select FollowerUserId, 'FD' From Table Where FollowingUserId =1
Union
Select FollowingUserId, 'FG' From Table Where FollowerUserId =1;
```

with above i get user 2 as

```
2,FG 
2,FD
```

from above **but I really need 2,B** without UserId 2 duplicated.
How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation on your basic query:

```
SELECT UserId,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT which) = 1 THEN MIN(which)
             ELSE 'B'
        END)
FROM (Select FollowerUserId as UserId, 'FD' as which From Table Where FollowingUserId = 1
      Union ALL
      Select FollowingUserId, 'FG' From Table Where FollowerUserId = 1
     ) f
GROUP BY UserId;
```